# Using C# to bind a new certificate for Custom Domains from Azure Api Management Service

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-management-api

I have tried to get the APIM Client and I figured it out that with apiManagement.Service.HostnameConfigurations I can get some information about what is it inside Custom Domains, information about the Certificate, but there is no method to upload a new one or change it with a new one. I can only modify the information of an actual one like Expiry date, thumbprint etc.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var apiManagementClient = new ApiManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(KeyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var certificate = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync(certificateName);
var apiManagementService = await apiManagementClient.ApiManagementService.GetAsync(
                 resourceGroupName,
                 serviceName);
var certificateList = apiManagementClient.Certificate.ListByService(resourceGroupName, serviceName);
var certificateExpiryDate = certificateList.FirstOrDefault(l=>l.Name.Equals(certificateName)).ExpirationDate;
var certificateThumbprint = certificateList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name.Equals(certificateName)).Thumbprint;
var certificateInformation = new CertificateInformation
            {
                Expiry = certificateExpiryDate,
                Subject = "",
                Thumbprint = certificateName,
            };
var customDomain = apiManagementService.HostnameConfigurations.FirstOrDefault(v => v.CertificateSource.Equals("KeyVault"));
customDomain.Certificate = certificateInformation;
```

Comment: I would use a powershell script : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/get-certificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: That doesn't help me. I need it in C#

Comment: Use the powershell class inside c#.  The PS methods are more robust than trying same in c#.  Powershell is written in Net Library so the code is equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update APIM service hostname configuration via [UpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.apimanagement.iapimanagementserviceoperations.updatewithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview) operation. Pass your custom hostname information in `HostnameConfigurations` property.

`Type` property specifies for what endpoint in APIM you want custom domain.

`CertificateSource` property specifies where certificate is coming from:

- Managed - certificate is provided by APIM itself. It's more complicated as you need to prove domain name ownership. See: [Managed Certificate support for Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-managed-certificate-support-for-azure-api-management/)
- KeyVault - certificate should be taken by APIM from KeyVault you provide. Make sure APIM identity has access to key vault and specify: `KeyVaultId`, and possibly `IdentityClientId`
- Custom - your own custom SSL certificate. Specify: `EncodedCertificate` and `CertificatePassword`
- BuiltIn - says to use APIM's built in certificates, can only be used with APIM's default domain names.